# How to disable expand collapse hints on collapsible panel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I want disable hints expand/collapse on expand/collapse button of collapsible panel.

[Kill it!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4oG9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-expandToolText):

```
expandToolText: false
```